# How to change Section/sub-section Numbering?

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

```
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\title{Some XYZ Title}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}


 \begin{document}
```

Whenever I am adding a list of figures & list of tables, the naming of my sections/subsection/subsubsection changes from 1 / 1.1 / 1.1.1 to A / A.1 A.1.1 How do i Solve this?

```
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{appendix}
        \listoffigures
    \listoftables
\end{appendix}
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section {Introduction}

\subsection {Introduction to Project Work}
For centuries, we have used symbols on
```

Comment: There is no `appendix` environment in standard classes. Try just writing the `\appendix` switch, and enclose your appendix stuff with a pair of braces.

Comment: Sorry, That isnt working. its still the same

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. It is *after* your appendix that numbering of sections, &c. begin with `A`?

Comment: yes. exactly. but if i remove the apendix, the numbering of sections reverts back to 1, 1.1 or so (which is what i want with the appendix)

Comment: I don't understand this question at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with the `appendices` environment from the `appendix` package. Here is a code that works. I managed to put the appendices in the table of contents, but if you don't want them, it's easy to undo.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[toc, title, titletoc] {appendix}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\title{Some XYZ Title}
\author{Myself}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\begin{appendices}      
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{List of Figures}
  \listoffigures
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{List of Tables}
  \listoftables
\end{appendices}
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section {Introduction}

\subsection {Introduction to Project Work}
For centuries, we have used symbols on

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that placing `\addcontentsline`s *after* `\listoffigures` and/or `\listoftables` could have problems if these lists span multiple pages. Your example works, but only because they are both fit on a single page.

Comment: Actually, I'm not much used to do it by hand: when I have to incorporate such lists in the table of contents, I do it via `\titleformat` of  `titlesec` and the `numberless` key. Thanks for pointing the problem. Code corrected.